# JQuery add a class to a table row depending on <td> value

Tags: jquery

I need to check the text of values in a table inside of a div. If one of values inside a `<td></td>` equals "INVALID", I want to add the class "red" to the `<tr>`.

The html looks like this -

```
<div id="MyDiv">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
           <td>1</td>
           <td>GOOD</td>      
        </tr>
        <tr>       
           <td>2</td>
           <td>INVALID</td>      
        </tr>
        <tr>       
           <td>3</td>
           <td>GOOD</td>      
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I have JQuery which will find *any* table on the page, and puts the class on the `<td>`. How can I change this to add the class to the `<tr>` inside a certain `<div>`?

```
    jQuery.each($('tbody tr td'), function () {
        if (this.textContent == "INVALID") {
            $(this).addClass("red");
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (this.textContent == "INVALID") {
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass("red");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call the [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method

```
jQuery.each($('tbody tr td'), function () {
    if (this.textContent == "INVALID") {
        $(this).parent().addClass("red");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$('tbody tr td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "INVALID") {
        $(this).parent().addClass("red");
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hMssR/